# how can I inject gradle ext properties

Tags: java, gradle, quarkus, microprofile

I am trying to pass project version and compilation time to my Quarkus project via build.gradle and GradleExtraProperties.

I have in my gradle.build file:

```
version '0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

ext {
   buildTime = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(new Date())
}
```

and in my Java source:

```java
   @ConfigProperty(name = "version")
   String version;
   
   @ConfigProperty(name="buildTime")
   String buildTime;
```

While *version* gets properly injected, *buildTime* fails with

```
ConfigurationException: Failed to load config value of type class java.lang.String for: buildTime
```

Does anybody know if and how that can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "buildTime", defaultValue="defaultValue")
String buildTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple and much more embarrassing: If one runs Quarkus in dev mode, Gradle does not build the project.
After I run `gradew build` everything was just fine.
SMH